# What is the Difference between IHttpClientFactory and HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

What happens when we create client object using

`var client=new HttpClient();`

And when we use IHttpClientFactory
`builder.Services.AddHttpClient();`

and using it through Dependency Injection

```
        public readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
        
        public RequestController(ClientPolicy clientPolicy,IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }
 
       var client= _clientFactory.CreateClient();
```

Comment: A quick googling reveals you can find your answers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

Comment: @Mohi have answered my own Question can you kindly verify it

Answer (score 0):

The Answer learnt from the above comment and articles is that when an HttpClient is Disposed its socket not disposed so soon that's why it create Socket Exhaustion problem and if we create singleton object of HttpClient then there will be DNS Error that's why in . Net core we implements IHttpClientFactory so it can overcome Socket Exhaustion problem and DNS Problem and its easy to maintain IHttpClientFactory at a single class in case of code modifications it will be implemented